# Is there anyway to make the AI defend or evade?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I'm finding the special attacks from bosses to be very difficult to deal with since the AI doesn't seem smart enough to actually block or evade these attacks. I can manage against a single-target special by switching to the AI and forcing them to block, but special attacks which hit the entire party seem to be impossible to deal with. I have a hard time believing there is no way for me to defend my party against these attacks, which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong.

Is there some way to force the AI to block or evade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "All Out Defense" command (this is a story reward) this makes your AI party members focus on using the Defend/Evade commands and will also focus on healing, but it really burns through MP.

Like other commands there's a timer, so you'll have to select it again if you need it, when it run out.